# Looking for a way to write this expression on latex

Tags: math-operators

Looking for a way to write this expression with LaTeX, I'm using the online Overleaf, but I can see no way to sort this out. The expression consists of a nabla symbol with a ring on it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5):

`\overset` is *not* the right way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathring{\Gamma}^{\lambda}\quad \mathring{\nabla}_{\mu}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank  you, I was actually looking for the symbol command \mathring{} I didn't know it.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\overset{\circ}{\nabla} \mu$
\end{document}
```

[image]